# Generate ManyToManyField Use SQL

Tags: sql, django, many-to-many

I have two models

```
class A(models.Model):
      m = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class B(models.Model):
      s = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

and now I want to add a ManyToManyField to A:

```
class A(models.Model):
      m = models.CharField(max_length=128)
      n = models.ManyToManyField('B',related_name='b_s',null=True,blank=True)
```

table a and b are already exist.How can I use SQL to add the third table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [django-south](http://south.aeracode.org/)

Comment: thank you! I use the "python manage.py sqlall appname" find the sql

Comment: For the sake of context, the solution @Danfi settled on, using `sqlall`, was suggested in freenode#django